# Can i use document.getelmentbytagname within geteval method in selenium?

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium-rc

following code is write are not:

```
selenium.GetEval("document.getElementsByTagName('a')[1].innerText");
```

actually other scripts are working fine like `document.getElementById` also `getElementsByTagName('form')`. but a tag is not working while executing the **rc testcase**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write this way:-

```
   String aStr = "{" +
                 " var aElem = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]; " +
                 " aElem.innerText; " +
                 "}";
   selenium.getEval(aStr);
```

**OR**

```
   String aStr = "{" +
                 " var aElem = window.document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]; " +
                 " aElem.innerText; " +
                 "}";
  selenium.getEval(aStr);
```

Comment: it is working fine.But the innerText result is NaN. what can i do?

Comment: Please check your hyperlink tag is closed without any innerText. Something like this `<a href="XXX" />`

Comment: it is working fine.But the innerText result is NaN or undefined. what can i do?

Comment: it is gave correct result in javascript but in getEval not working

Answer (score 0):

`document` in `GetEval()` isn't the document you think it is.  You should use `selenium.browserbot.GetCurrentWindow().document` instead of `document` any time you're using `GetEval()`.